# Drawing Circles Along a Line Using Recursion & Fractals - Java

Tags: java, recursion, geometry, draw, fractals

I am trying to draw the following fractal pattern of circles along a line.
It draws a circle with a radius of n, and a center point on an invisible line. It then recursively draws two circles with a radius of n/2 and center points on line where the circles cross the line.
[image: Fractal Circles]
This is very confusing to me as the Java graphics code for drawing circles requires you to use "instance.drawOval(int x1, int x1, int height, int width) - which says nothing about the center of the circle.

I have tried  to take a stab at it and this is what I have come up with so far. I have only tried to draw the first circle and then the two to the right and left. I have not done any of the recursion as of yet. I am simply trying to draw two circles to the left and right whose center points collide with the left and right of the largest circle.

```
 package fractalcircles;

 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class FractalCircles {

 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   //create a MyCanvas object
    MyCanvas canvas1 = new MyCanvas();

    //set up a JFrame to hold the canvas
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("FractalCircles.java");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLocation(100,100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //add the canvas to the frame as a content panel
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }//end main
 }//end class

 class MyCanvas extends Canvas
 {
public MyCanvas()
{} //end MyCanvas() constructor

//this method will draw the initial circle and invisible line
public void paint (Graphics graphics)
{
    int n=50; //radius of first circle

    //draw invisible line
    graphics.drawLine(0,250,500,250);

    //draw first circle
    graphics.drawOval(200,200,n*2,n*2);

    //run fractal algorith to draw 2 circles to the left and right
    drawCircles(graphics, n);
}

public void drawCircles (Graphics graphics, int n)
{
    int x1; int y1; //top left corner of left circle to be drawn
    int x2; int y2; //top left corner of right circle to be drawn

    //drawing left circle
    x1=200-((n/2)*2); 
    //***this math was found using the equation in chapter 11
    //***center point of circle = (x+(width/2), y+(height/2))
    y1=200-((n/2)*2);
    graphics.drawOval(x1, y1, ((n/2)*2), ((n/2)*2));

    //drawing right circle
    x2=300-((n/2)*2);
    y2=300-((n/2)*2);
    graphics.drawOval(x1, y1, ((n/2)*2), ((n/2)*2));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to throw in a little tip. If the task would be easier and you would rather draw circles from the center, lets make a function that works the way you want it to.

```
public void circle(Graphics g, int centerX, int centerY, int radius) {
    g.drawOval(centerX-radius, centerY-radius, radius*2+1, radius*2+1) 
}
```

Now you have a function that can make circles from a center point of your choosing with a radius of your choosing.

Yay!